# Different random number generation between OS

Tags: r, random

Does anyone have any experience with situations where set.seed gives different results depending on operating system (OS). I remember coming across a similar situation in a class  on R before where some people were generating different random sequences using rnorm despite setting the starting seed to the same value.
Now, I'm giving a course myself and have not run into the same issue with rnorm; all my students get the same sequence regardless of OS. Interestingly, the same issue seems to exist with the mvrnorm function of the MASS package.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated - Marc

This example:

```
require(MASS)
set.seed(123)
a <- rnorm(10, mean=10, sd=3)
b <- rnorm(10, mean=5, sd=2)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
C <- cov(df)
M <- mvrnorm(n=10, c(10,5), C)

df
C
M
```

Yields on my Windows 7 OS 64-bit version of R 2.14.1.:

```
> df
           a        b
1   8.318573 7.448164
2   9.309468 5.719628
3  14.676125 5.801543
4  10.211525 5.221365
5  10.387863 3.888318
6  15.145195 8.573826
7  11.382749 5.995701
8   6.204816 1.066766
9   7.939441 6.402712
10  8.663014 4.054417
> C
         a        b
a 8.187336 3.431373
b 3.431373 4.310385
> M
              a        b
 [1,] 13.270535 6.158603
 [2,] 10.375011 5.737871
 [3,] 13.514105 5.476411
 [4,] 12.681956 5.020646
 [5,] 12.352333 4.927746
 [6,] 15.177508 6.810387
 [7,]  8.114377 2.925225
 [8,]  9.529744 4.834451
 [9,] 12.903550 7.232715
[10,]  6.251907 3.481789
```

Edit: It might be helpful to know if anyone is not getting these results and what OS or versions of R were used.

Comment: Were you all using the same version of R and/or the same RNGkind?

Comment: @Dason - No, I don't think so. In some cases, they might have newer versions of R than myself. But I think, even between students, they were getting different results and OS seemed like a possible common denominator.

Comment: No its not. R generates the RNGs itself, and the only possible difference maybe the matrix decomposition needed if you do `mvrnorm` -- and that may be due to the LAPACK/BLAS libraries.  If you draw just sequential vectors, I am pretty certain you will get the same numbers.  R pays attention to these things.

Comment: Two students that were definitely getting different results were using one of these mini-laptop computers. I don't believe it runs a typical Windows OS, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard of people changing the RNGKind, sometimes without realizing it by loading and running a package that changed the generator or some other script that made the change.  If that was the case then the same seed would lead to different random numbers.  A fresh running of R (without loading different packages or other scripts) should generate the same random numbers from the same seed.

Comment: Also possibly run `rm(list=ls(all.names=TRUE))` first thing upon opening the R session, in case a `.Random.seed` is lying around from a previously saved workspace.