# Different random number generation between OS in R

Tags: r, random

I'm getting slightly different random numbers depending on the OS (Mac vs Linux):

```
set.seed(890458, kind="Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind="Inversion")
print(rlnorm(1504)[1504], digits=22)
sessionInfo()
```

Linux:

```
> set.seed(890458, kind="Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind="Inversion")
> print(rlnorm(1504)[1504], digits=22)
[1] 2.732876214731374542311

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.7.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0    digest_0.6.12
```

Mac:

```
> set.seed(890458, kind="Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind="Inversion")
> print(rlnorm(1504)[1504], digits=22)
[1] 2.732876214731374098221

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 digest_0.6.12
```

Is this expected? Is there anyway to guarantee reproducibility across platforms? It also happens with rnorm rather than rlnorm but with higher numbers.

Comment: With MS R-open 3.2.5, 64 bit on Windows 7, I get `2.732876214731374542311` which agrees with the Linux output. (I used `sprintf("%.21f", rlnorm(1504)[1504])`).

Comment: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/310

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567613/different-random-number-generation-between-os

Comment: Maybe some settings of `kind` other than `"Mersenne-Twister"` would be immune from this behavior, which is possibly due to different `BLAS` libraries (though just how I have no idea).

Comment: Your two numbers differ in the 15th decimal place.  Are you hitting the limit on accuracy of real numbers for the different systems?  Perhaps modify your code to see the bit pattern (or hex) produced rather than munging the random bits through a conversion to real.  If the bit-patterns are the same then your problem is in the way the two different OSes handle reals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Erratic seed behavior with rbinom(prob=0.5) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907600/erratic-seed-behavior-with-rbinomprob-0-5-in-r)

Comment: @rossum Using the package [seven31](https://www.github.com/ThinkRstat/seven31) the bit pattern of the numers are reveled as: `0 10000000000 (    1) 0101110111001110111000110100011100100100110011011011 and 0 10000000000 (    1) 0101110111001110111000110100011100100100110011011010". They are different but only in the last bit.

Comment: Perhaps you could pull one more bit out of the two Mersenne Twister implementation and drop the last bit?  Would that make them the same?

Comment: You generally should't evaluate IEEE 754 double-precision values beyond the 15th significant digit. Try using `digits=14` for a more stable comparison.

Comment: I'm getting `2.732876214731374542311` on MacOS 13.0 and R 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem of the randomness generating algorithms. It is impossible. The way any pseudo random number generator on a computer works is that it produces sequences of numbers with minimal correlation over various distances. Even if you get a single bit of the internal state different, the resulting sequences of numbers are **entirely** different. It is impossible to get **slightly** different random numbers.

Also note, all good random number algorithms use integer internal states. The floating point output is "artificial".

In your example the problem, thus, must be outside the actual random number generator. Also, the randomness of any generator is really limited. It makes likely no sense to use "digits=22". There must a precision-difference somewhere in the Mac and Linux libraries. That's interesting and potentially concerning - but as I argue, not related to the random number algorithms.