# In R, how can I get PRNG to give identical floating point numbers between platforms?

Tags: r, random, floating-point, cross-platform

Running the following code in R 4.1.1 gives different results between platforms.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(3)[3]
print(x, 22)

# -0.83562861241004716      # intel windows
# -0.8356286124100471557341 # m1 mac

print(round(x, 15), 22)
# -0.83562861241004704      # intel windows
# -0.8356286124100470447118 # m1 mac
```

I know the size of difference is below `.Machine$double.eps` and the extra digits do not carry meaningful information.

I am not happy with the fact that extra digits exist. How can I ensure exactly consistent results? Is there an RNG library that achieves this?

**EDIT:**

The bit representation is different.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
x <- sum(x)
SoDA::binaryRep(x)

.10101110001110000100001111110111000010011001011111011 # intel windows
.10101110001110000100001111110111000010011001011111110 # m1 mac
```

Bits are also different in `runif()`. This suggests that the uniform-to-gaussian conversion is not the only breaking point.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10000000)
x <- sum(x)
SoDA::binaryRep(x)

# kind = "Mersenne-Twister"
.10011000100101000110100110111100101000100000101100000 # intel windows
.10011000100101000110100110111100101000011111001100000 # m1 mac
# kind = "Wichmann-Hill"
.10011000100111111110101000100001001001010100000011011 # intel windows
.10011000100111111110101000100001001001010100001001010 # m1 mac
# kind = "Marsaglia-Multicarry"
.10011000100011100110000010000001011100011110100001110 # intel windows
.10011000100011100110000010000001011100011110001010000 # m1 mac
# kind = "Super-Duper"
.10011000100010011010010110100001000101100011101011110 # intel windows
.10011000100010011010010110100001000101100100001111101 # m1 mac
# kind = "Knuth-TAOCP-2002"
.10011000101000110101010111000111010011101001000101100 # intel windows
.10011000101000110101010111000111010011101001000101101 # m1 mac
# kind = "Knuth-TAOCP"
.10011000100110001011010011000001011001001110011111000 # intel windows
.10011000100110001011010011000001011001001110011111001 # m1 mac
# kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG"
.10011000100100010110100101101001011000000111010110101 # intel windows
.10011000100100010110100101101001011000001000010100001 # m1 mac
```

Comment: I'm surprised by this but don't have easy access to a Windows machine to test.  What do you get on Windows vs MacOS if you `print(pi, 22)` ... ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567613/different-random-number-generation-between-os https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679984/different-random-number-generation-between-os-in-r . It would be interesting to know if the problem persists with other `RNGkind()` settings, which would point to cross-platform detailed changes with Mersenne Twister.

Comment: @BenBolker Windows: `3.141592653589793**1**`, MacOS: `3.141592653589793**115998**` (incorrect digits in bold)

Comment: @BenBolker Using `RNGkind("Wichmann-Hill")` also gives extra digits in MacOS.

Comment: It took a while to find (almost as much as it would have to write it myself), but: can you try installing the `SoDA` package and call `binaryRep()` on both platforms ... ?

Comment: @PeterO. I cannot rule out whether the implementations of `print` are different, but the bit representations of the numbers are different. I edited the post with more information about this.

Comment: Hmm. Can you check with SoDA::binaryRep() as well? (I believe you but ...)

Comment: @BenBolker I edited the post with it. Last few bits are different.

Comment: Thanks for being so responsive. Can you confirm that the bit pattern of `pi` is the *same* on both machines?  Is the bit pattern of Wichman-Hill different? (I suspect a *combination* of printing differences and true differences in bit patterns might be muddling things up, so I'm trying to rule out possible differences in printing ...)  (The fact that `pi` gives different results **strongly** points to printing differences in addition to whatever else is going on ...)

Comment: Some of the PRNGs do (almost?) entirely integer and bit-shift operations internally: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/980c4748f479f3ae02cb596862a46eb9a3087584/src/main/RNG.c#L109-L145 .  This is why I want to do some comparisons for some of the other built-in RNG types (Wichman-Hill, Marsaglia-multicarry)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the help. The bit pattern of `pi` is identical on both machines. The sum of 100 normal values from Wichmann-Hill are different in the last 4 bits in `SoDA::binaryRep()`.

Comment: Oops, I also see that we're using `rnorm`, not `runif`. So the unif -> Gaussian algorithm ("inversion" by default) could also be implicated.

Comment: what about sum of 100 `runif()` W-H  values?  `runif()` + Marsaglia-multicarry? `runif` + Mersenne twister? (I'm not trying to make trouble/add extra work, just doing the best I can to diagnose remotely ...)

Comment: @PeterO. Thanks for the pointer. I am trying to make simulation results exactly reproducible. Is there a way to force it to not use extended precisions?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do so at the R level.  In any case, extended precision is only one way (among a host of others) that floating-point arithmetic might lead to non-reproducible pseudorandom numbers.  By contrast, integer arithmetic has fewer reproducibility problems, but I don't think the R language has any native integer types.

Comment: @BenBolker `runif()` + Mersenne twister: identical. W-H: the last bit is different. M-M: identical.

Comment: R does have native integer types (32-bit built in, 64-bit through the `bit64` package), but I'm not really sure you want to get into rolling all of your own PRNG machinery. If your simulation itself has any floating-point machinery in it, you're likely to have more of the same kinds of headaches.  How big is your Lyapunov exponent anyway ... ??

Comment: so if `runif` + Mersenne twister is consistently identical (try a few different examples), then you can move on and see if one of the `normal.kind` options in `?RNGkind` is safe at the level you want it to be (Kinderman-Ramage, Box-Muller, Ahrens-Dieter).

Comment: I had a simulation which began with generating floating point numbers and produced an integer value. The workload was split into different platforms which in retrospect I think was a mistake for the sake of reproducibility. When I tried to reproduce it later, I was getting different integer values sometimes even with the same seed and this led me to this rabbit hole. I am not familiar with Lyapunov exponent, but you get the idea. I was getting integer scale differences.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and being so responsive with your queries. It seems if there is a specific `RNGkind` that works then I could use it, and if nothing works then I should forget about it as there is a chance that internal precision is involved.

Comment: The fact the differences are small implies the issue is not in the core random number generator but is in the conversion of a sample selected from a uniform distribution to the Gaussian distribution. If so, one solution would be to get uniform samples directly and use your own code to convert them to Gaussian. That presumes R supports reproducible floating-point operations, i.e., that you can write R code to do the conversion that will produce identical results from identical inputs.

Comment: I still think you might be able to find one of the three other available `normal.kind` settings that would solve your problem for the time being (i.e. one that happens not to use different precisions on different platforms ...) (I'm excluding "buggy Kinderman-Ramage", which is only provided for backward compatibility ...)

Comment: I edited the post with more information. `runif()` is inconsistent across all `kind` settings.

Comment: Have you managed to address this issue?

Comment: @PeterO. No, this is in my backlog for now. It looks like I would have to manually implement it using the way you described. The paper mentions it being available in `MPFR`, but the `Rmpfr` package does not have a `rnorm()` equivalent function. For now I am satisfied with knowing what was causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Comments from Oct. 29 and Nov. 2 moved here and edited.)

I should note that such subtle [reproducibility issues](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Ensuring_Reproducibility) with pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) can occur when floating-point arithmetic is involved. For instance, Intel's instruction set architecture might make use of 80-bit extended precision for internal arithmetic. Extended precision, though, is only one way (among a host of others) that floating-point arithmetic might lead to non-reproducible pseudorandom numbers. Consider that Intel's and Arm's instruction set architectures are different enough to cause reproducibility issues. (If I understand, an Arm instruction set is what is used in Apple's M1 chip.)

By contrast, integer arithmetic has fewer reproducibility problems.

Thus, if bit-for-bit reproducibility matters to you, you should try to find an R language PRNG that uses only integer operations. (Indeed, computers generate pseudorandom floating-point numbers via integers, not the other way around, and most PRNGs produce integers, not floating-point numbers.)

For instance, for uniform variates, take the integer output of the Mersenne Twister algorithm without manipulating it. For Gaussian (and exponential) random variates, there is fortunately an [algorithm by Karney](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.6257.pdf) that generates arbitrary-precision variates with only integer operations. Also, consider rational arithmetic built on underlying integer operations.

REFERENCES:

Karney, C.F.F., 2016. Sampling exactly from the normal distribution. ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software (TOMS), 42(1), pp.1-14.

Comment: "Consider that Intel's and Arm's instruction set architectures are different enough to cause reproducibility issues." <- I'd be interested to know more here; do you have a link? Apart from the availability of extended precision on Intel, are there other aspects of floating-point that differ between the two architectures?

Comment: @Mark Dickinson : I don't know, unfortunately.  I have understood extended precision (and its effect on floating-point results) as an Intel-only behavior that doesn't apply to the M1 or other Arm-based processors.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it would make sense that most (all?) ARM designs don't support any form of Intel-like 80-bit extended precision. I'd be interested in anything that shows that ARM introduces _new_ reproducibility issues on top of those that we're familiar with for x86_64 development (x87 vs SSE2, intermediate expressions evaluated with extra precision, use of fma or not, compiler flags and fast math "optimizations", libm implementation differences, subnormal handling and FTZ / DAZ flags, etc.).